# Create tables with conditional formatting with RMarkdown + knitr

Tags: r, knitr

I have a data frame and I want to output this in an HTML file through knitr and RMarkdown as a table with conditional formatting.  Example:

```
n <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,1,1,1), y = c(0,1,0,1,0))
> n
  x y
1 1 0
2 1 1
3 1 0
4 1 1
5 1 0
```

I want rows with different values of x and y to be highlighted.  So in this case, that would be rows 1, 3 and 5.  Would be nice if the output in the HTML file would be an HTML table, but failing that an image would be fine as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25315309/conditional-formatting-tables-in-rmarkdown-documents suggests the ReportRs package, FlexTable

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I always wanted to extend `pandoc.table` in my [pander package](http://rapporter.github.com/pander/) with this feature, but failed to get the time for that. But this question is really inspiring, probably will do that in the next few days. Until then, what about:

1. Load the package:

   ```
   library(pander)
   ```
2. Load your data:

   ```
   n <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,1,1,1), y = c(0,1,0,1,0))
   ```
3. Update your lines to be marked as **strong** in Pandoc:

   ```
   for (i in c(1, 3, 5))
       n[i, ] <- pandoc.strong.return(n[1, ])
   ```
4. Show the markdown version of your table:

   ```
   pandoc.table(n)
   pander(n)       # S3 method
   ```
5. Covert the markdown to e.g. HTML with `brew` syntax:

   ```
   Pandoc.brew(text = '<%=n%>', output = tempfile(), convert = 'html')
   ```

---

**Update:** I have updated `pander` to take some new arguments to highlight rows/columns/cells easily. Although I am still working on some further helper functions to make this process easier, here goes a quick demo so that you might see how it could help your workflow:

```
> pandoc.table(n, emphasize.rows = c(1, 3, 5))

-------
 x   y 
--- ---
*1* *0*

 1   1 

*0* *1*

 1   1 

*1* *0*
-------

> pandoc.table(n, emphasize.strong.cells = which(n == 1, arr.ind = TRUE))

-----------
  x     y  
----- -----
**1**   0  

**1** **1**

**1**   0  

**1** **1**

**1**   0  
-----------
```

---

**Update:** `pander` gained some helper functions to highlight cells in the tables even easier:

```
> t <- mtcars[1:3, 1:5]
> emphasize.cols(1)
> emphasize.rows(1)
> pandoc.table(t)

----------------------------------------------------
      &nbsp;         mpg    cyl   disp   hp    drat 
------------------- ------ ----- ------ ----- ------
   **Mazda RX4**     *21*   *6*  *160*  *110* *3.9* 

 **Mazda RX4 Wag**   *21*    6    160    110   3.9  

  **Datsun 710**    *22.8*   4    108    93    3.85 
----------------------------------------------------
```

Or directly with `pander` method:

```
> emphasize.strong.cells(which(t > 20, arr.ind = TRUE))
> pander(t)

---------------------------------------------------------
      &nbsp;          mpg     cyl   disp     hp     drat 
------------------- -------- ----- ------- ------- ------
   **Mazda RX4**     **21**    6   **160** **110**  3.9  

 **Mazda RX4 Wag**   **21**    6   **160** **110**  3.9  

  **Datsun 710**    **22.8**   4   **108** **93**   3.85 
---------------------------------------------------------
```

*Please note that these new features are not published on CRAN yet, but you can find in the most recent version hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/Rapporter/pander).*

Answer (score 18):

Here a solution based on `xtable` with a custom `css`.  I think the solution is flexible since once you get it work , you can customize your html tables indefinitely if you know some css tricks.

Here we go. The solution consist in 3 files:

1. a css file where I alternate table row color.

   ```
   table {
      max-width: 95%;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
   }

   th {
     background-color: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
   }

   table tr:nth-child(odd) td{
      background-color: #FF0000;
   }
   table tr:nth-child(even) td{
       background-color: #00FFFF;
   }
   ```
2. an R script file to set RStudio markdown  with the following content:

   ```
   options(rstudio.markdownToHTML = 
         function(inputFile, outputFile) {      
           require(markdown)
           markdownToHTML(inputFile, outputFile, stylesheet='customstyle.css')   
         }
   )
   ```
3. create a new markdown with the following:

   ````
   ```{r}
    source('initmd.R')
   ```


   ```{r,results='asis'}
   library(xtable)
   n <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,1,1,1), y = c(0,1,0,1,0))
   print(xtable(n),type='html')
   ```
   ````

finally convert the markdwon to html using `knit HTML` button and you should get something like this :

[image]