# Formatting html table in R

Tags: html, r, xtable

I would like to improve the look of an `html` table that I generate in R using the package `xtable`:

```
 library(xtable)
 
 html.table = xtable(<mydataframe>)
 digits(html.table) = 2
```

I print the table using:

```
 html.tab = print(html.table, type = "html", floating = FALSE)
 cat(html.tab, file = <html link>)
```

I would like to be able to justify the text in the table, modify the color of the header column, change the font, ...

Is there any way I can achieve that in R?

Comment: What is the point of downvoting a post without including a comment explaining why?

Comment: This answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15403903/create-tables-with-conditional-formatting-with-rmarkdown-knitr/15405068#15405068) should help you.

Comment: @agstudy Thank you very much. I am very beginner at HTML but this should help me understand. Thanks.

Comment: I think it question of styling here (css) not HTML. Th HTML is created by print.xtable , you should decorate it with some css classes.

Comment: I understand, thank you. Once the css file is created, I am not sure how to use it to format a table that I created using `xtable()`. I couldn't follow all the steps described in the link you provided, as I still don't understand much about the package `xtable`. Could you please help me with that? Thanks

Comment: For an alternative to xtable, see htmlTable which can create almost any html-table, and has a css.cell argument, which takes a matrix with your css for each cell: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/htmlTable/vignettes/general.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to :

1. Create a css where you format "stylize" your table using some css features
2. Create a html table using `print.xtable`
3. Create a file including a link to the css file and the created html table

So here the code creating the "res.html" file:

```
## a dummy data.frame used as an example
library(xtable)
n <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,1,1,1), y = c(0,1,0,1,0))
## the html header  
## here I am using a link to mystyle.css 
html.head <- paste("<head>" ,
             '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css"/>',
             "</head>",sep='\n')
## the html body
html.table <- paste(print(xtable(n),type='html','res.html'), 
                    collapse = "\n")
html.body <- paste("<body>", html.table,"</body>")
## the html file
write(paste(html.head,html.body,sep='\n'),"res.html")
```

the syle sheet file(mystyle.css) can contain be something like this :

```
table {
   max-width: 95%;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

th {
  background-color: #000000; // background for table header 
  color: #ffffff;
}

td
{
   text-align:right;        // justify column
   background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your thorough explanation. However, for some reason, it didn't work for me. Should I save the stylesheet in a specific directory, or can I save it anywhere and refer to it using its full path?

Comment: Also, if I am writing other things along with the table, I am assuming that all the code should be included in `html.body`?

Comment: @Mariam here  href="mystyle.css" means that the style file in the same location as the html file. It is a relative path.( relative to the html location). For example, href="css/mystyle.css" means that the style is stored in css directory.

Answer (score 9):

with xtable you can also give a class or id (or inline css) in the `<TABLE>` tag with the `html.table.attributes` argument. 
an example:

```
print(xtable(head(iris, 10)), type = "html", include.rownames = F, 
      html.table.attributes="class='table-bordered'")
```

this returns:

```
<!-- html table generated in R 3.0.1 by xtable 1.7-3 package -->
<!-- Fri Jul 11 12:18:15 2014 -->
<TABLE class='table table-bordered'>
<TR> <TH> Sepal.Length </TH> <TH> Sepal.Width </TH> <TH> Petal.Length </TH> <TH> Petal.Width </TH> <TH> Species </TH>  </TR>
<TR> <TD align="right"> 5.10 </TD> <TD align="right"> 3.50 </TD> <TD align="right"> 1.40 </TD> <TD align="right"> 0.20 </TD> <TD> setosa </TD> </TR>
<TR> <TD align="right"> 4.90 </TD> <TD align="right"> 3.00 </TD> <TD align="right"> 1.40 </TD> <TD align="right"> 0.20 </TD> <TD> setosa </TD> </TR>
<TR> <TD align="right"> 4.70 </TD> <TD align="right"> 3.20 </TD> <TD align="right"> 1.30 </TD> <TD align="right"> 0.20 </TD> <TD> setosa </TD> </TR>
<TR> <TD align="right"> 4.60 </TD> <TD align="right"> 3.10 </TD> <TD align="right"> 1.50 </TD> <TD align="right"> 0.20 </TD> <TD> setosa </TD> </TR>
<TR> <TD align="right"> 5.00 </TD> <TD align="right"> 3.60 </TD> <TD align="right"> 1.40 </TD> <TD align="right"> 0.20 </TD> <TD> setosa </TD> </TR>
<TR> <TD align="right"> 5.40 </TD> <TD align="right"> 3.90 </TD> <TD align="right"> 1.70 </TD> <TD align="right"> 0.40 </TD> <TD> setosa </TD> </TR>
<TR> <TD align="right"> 4.60 </TD> <TD align="right"> 3.40 </TD> <TD align="right"> 1.40 </TD> <TD align="right"> 0.30 </TD> <TD> setosa </TD> </TR>
<TR> <TD align="right"> 5.00 </TD> <TD align="right"> 3.40 </TD> <TD align="right"> 1.50 </TD> <TD align="right"> 0.20 </TD> <TD> setosa </TD> </TR>
<TR> <TD align="right"> 4.40 </TD> <TD align="right"> 2.90 </TD> <TD align="right"> 1.40 </TD> <TD align="right"> 0.20 </TD> <TD> setosa </TD> </TR>
<TR> <TD align="right"> 4.90 </TD> <TD align="right"> 3.10 </TD> <TD align="right"> 1.50 </TD> <TD align="right"> 0.10 </TD> <TD> setosa </TD> </TR>
</TABLE>
```

this class or id can be used in the ccs file, this can be useful if you create multiple tables 
for the html page

---

In addition you can use the `print.results=FALSE` argument to catch the character vector
and use functions from the stringr package e.g. `str_replace()`, `str_replace_all()`  to add classes, id's or inline css to other places in the table e.g. the `<TD>` tag