# Centering a Xtable in Rmarkdown html output

Tags: r, r-markdown, xtable

I'm using `xtable` to create a table in a HTML document in `rmarkdown`, the problem I have is that the output table is align to the left and I need it to be center. I tried with the `kable` package but then the table is to wide. The question is if there is a way to center tables in an HTML document, something like `fig.aling = 'center'` but for tables that doesn't require `LaTex`.

Comment: Im sure there will be an option but i dont know it offhand, but a quick fix is to add a little html: `tab = capture.output(print(xtable(mtcars[1:2, 1:4]), type="html", only.contents=TRUE)) ; cat(c('<table align="center", border=1>', tab, '</table>'), sep="\n")`

Comment: actually, there may be a way setting `html.table.attributes` argument : `print(xtable(mtcars[1:2, 1:4]), type = "html", 
      html.table.attributes=list('align="center", border=1' ))` . See tertra's answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20200082/formatting-html-table-in-r

Comment: @user20650 your second comment works perfect, if you want make it an answer and i'll accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking inspiration from [Formatting html table in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20200082/formatting-html-table-in-r#24695958) , you can add table attributes using the `html.table.attributes` argument of `print.xtable`.

So for example:

````
```{r, results='asis'}

library(xtable)

print(
   xtable(mtcars[1:2, 1:4], align="lcccc"), # align columns
   type = "html", 
   html.table.attributes = 'align="center", # center table in page
                            rules="rows",   # only keep horizontal rows
                            width=50%,      # increase table width to 50% page
                            frame="below"') # remove border except bottom rule

```
````