# Conditional formatting tables in RMarkdown documents

Tags: r, datatables, knitr, r-markdown

As an example, I might want to use the following rule to color the cells:

(edited to un-trivialize)

1. Blue if > 4
2. No fill if <= 4 and >= 3.5
3. Yellow if >= 3 and < 3.5
4. Orange if < 3

[Create tables with conditional formatting with RMarkdown + knitr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15403903/create-tables-with-conditional-formatting-with-rmarkdown-knitr)
doesn't help me because I don't just want to highlight cells satisfying one set of criteria.

Example rmd:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r, message = FALSE, results = "asis"}
library(knitr)
library(dplyr)
head(iris) %>% kable
```
````

I'll take a solution utilizing `DataTables` if that's what it takes

Comment: why dont you take that answer and generalize it to use n conditions and then answer your own question?

Comment: @rawr if I'm understanding it correctly, `pander` utilizes `*` and `**` from markdown to "tag" cells for highlighting, and hence will not generalize to n > 2. Well, I guess I have a bad example in the OP since n=2, but I'm looking for something more flexible.

Comment: For these three conditions, you can use markdown, e.g. use "strong emphasis" instead of "blue", "emphasis/italics" instead of "orange" and "no extra formatting" for "no fill".

Comment: if you are using html, you could search the table for specific values, say 4, and replace that value with, say `<td bgcolor="#00ff00">4</td>`, and voila! a green cell for all 4s

Comment: actually, I think this is deprecated in hmtl5, so best to use css: `<td style="background-color:green">`

Answer (score 8):

Hello here a solution using function `FlexTable` from package `ReporteRs`. This function is intended to create Word table but you can get the html code from FlexTable objects with `as.html` :

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---


```{r, results='asis', warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(ReporteRs)
data(iris)
irisFT = FlexTable( iris )

vars <- c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width")
for (i in vars) {
  irisFT[iris[, i] < 3, i] = cellProperties( background.color = "orange" )
  irisFT[iris[, i] >= 3 & iris[, i] < 3.5, i] = cellProperties( background.color = "yellow" )
  irisFT[iris[, i] > 4, i] = cellProperties( background.color = "#81DAF5" )
}

cat(as.html(irisFT))
```
````

[image]

For more example, please visit https://davidgohel.github.io/ReporteRs/articles/FlexTable.html

Comment: Note when printing: bootstrap print media style rules are added to your document by default and will print your table cells with a white (transparent) background. To reenable your cell colors, one option is to set your theme to null in your yaml front matter.

Answer (score -2):

`knitr` contain vignette with jQuery DataTables example.

```
vignette("datatables", package = "knitr")
```