# Is there a convenient way to make a heatmap-style table in knitr?

Tags: r, knitr

I'd like to be able to generate a table in knitr where the cell background color would be set according to a color gradient mapped to the values in the cells.

For an example, see [towards the bottom of this page](http://fivethirtyeight.com/features/indiana-is-weird/).

Pander appears to be able to do some kinds of conditional highlighting, [as described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15403903/create-tables-with-conditional-formatting-with-rmarkdown-knitr), but I can't find an option that would allow conditional formatting of cell background.

Comment: `pander` won't be able to help with coloring cells as that's not supported in `pandoc`'s markdown, but if you want eg HTML output and no need to generate other document formats, I warmly suggest giving https://github.com/renkun-ken/formattable a try.

Answer (score 2):

See for example the age column in the bottom of [that page](http://renkun.me/formattable/)

Comment: When the code for the formatted table you reference is included in a chunk of an .Rnw script (knitr and LaTeX), after library(formattable) has been called, there is an error message in the resulting pdf file: "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): could not find function formattable."  Does the package work for .Rnw and, e.g., xelatex?

Comment: @Dontas, that appears to be a broken link.

Answer (score 1):

I have accomplished this in LaTeX in the past simply by parsing the dataframe to be passed to `xtable`, and evaluating the table entries and just adding in the corresponding LaTeX color markup. For example, my LaTeX preamble includes this:

```
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.3}
\definecolor{blue0}{HTML}{E5E5FE}
\definecolor{blue1}{HTML}{CBCBFE}
\definecolor{blue2}{HTML}{B2B2FE}
\definecolor{blue3}{HTML}{9898FE}
\definecolor{blue4}{HTML}{7F7FFE}
\definecolor{blue5}{HTML}{6666FE}
\definecolor{blue6}{HTML}{4C4CFE}
\definecolor{blue7}{HTML}{3333FE}
\definecolor{blue8}{HTML}{1919FE}
\definecolor{blue9}{HTML}{0000FE}
```

and in my code I use this nested `for` loop (where `KnownResults` is a dataframe with numeric entries):

```
for(i in seq_along(colnames(KnownResults))){ 
  for(q in seq_along(rownames(KnownResults))){ 
    if(KnownResults[q,i]!="NA"){ 
          if(KnownResults[q,i] > 0.9){ 
            KnownResults[q,i] <- paste0("\\cellcolor{blue9}{", 
                                        "\\textcolor{white}{",
                                        formatC(KnownResults[q,i], format='f', digits=4 ),
                                        "}}")            
          } else if(KnownResults[q,i] > 0.8){
            KnownResults[q,i] <- paste0("\\cellcolor{blue8}{", 
                                        "\\textcolor{white}{",
                                        formatC(KnownResults[q,i], format='f', digits=4 ),
                                        "}}")
          } else if(KnownResults[q,i] > 0.7){
             KnownResults[q,i] <- paste0("\\cellcolor{blue7}{", 
                                        "\\textcolor{white}{",
                                        formatC(KnownResults[q,i], format='f', digits=4 ),
                                        "}}")
          } else if(KnownResults[q,i] > 0.6){
            KnownResults[q,i] <- paste0("\\cellcolor{blue6}{", 
                                        "\\textcolor{white}{",
                                        formatC(KnownResults[q,i], format='f', digits=4 ),
                                        "}}")
          } else if(KnownResults[q,i] > 0.5){
            KnownResults[q,i] <- paste0("\\cellcolor{blue5}{", 
                                        "\\textcolor{white}{",
                                        formatC(KnownResults[q,i], format='f', digits=4 ),
                                        "}}")
          } else if(KnownResults[q,i] > 0.4){            
            KnownResults[q,i] <- paste0("\\cellcolor{blue4}{",  
                                        formatC(KnownResults[q,i], format='f', digits=4 ),
                                        "}")
          } else if(KnownResults[q,i] > 0.3){
            KnownResults[q,i] <- paste0("\\cellcolor{blue3}{", 
                                        formatC(KnownResults[q,i], format='f', digits=4 ),
                                        "}")
          } else if(KnownResults[q,i] > 0.2){
            KnownResults[q,i] <- paste0("\\cellcolor{blue2}{", 
                                        formatC(KnownResults[q,i], format='f', digits=4 ),
                                        "}")
          } else if(KnownResults[q,i] > 0.1){
            KnownResults[q,i] <- paste0("\\cellcolor{blue1}{", 
                                        formatC(KnownResults[q,i], format='f', digits=4 ),
                                        "}")
          } else if(KnownResults[q,i] > 0.0){
            KnownResults[q,i] <- paste0("\\cellcolor{blue0}{", 
                                        formatC(KnownResults[q,i], format='f', digits=4 ),
                                        "}")
          } else {}

    } else { KnownResults[q,i]<-"NS"}
  }

}
```

I am sure you can modify this to suit your needs (and likely simplify the code!).

Also the gradient color values were predetermined using this code:

```
HPSColors<-colorRamp(c('white','blue'))
HPSColors<-rgb(HPSColors(seq(from=0.1,to=1.0,by=0.1)),maxColorValue=256)
```