# Empty td in Table after changing font-color (R)

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

Good afternoon,

I am working on a reactive table in shiny that shows if a person is allowed to go on holiday or not given various factors. On days where he is allowed it will say "OK" and on days that are not allowed it will say "DENIED". To add some flair to my table I decided to change the font weight and color to these verdicts like so:

```
dt.req_team[`Accepted?` == "OK", "Accepted?"] <- '<td style="color: limegreen; font-weight: bold;">OK</td>'
dt.req_team[`Accepted?` == "DENIED", "Accepted?"] <- '<td style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">DENIED</td>'
```

The font is changed perfectly however instead of editing the existing td it creates a new one, leaving the previous one empty. You can see this in the HTML:

```
<tr> 
  <td> 2020-09-10 </td> 
  <td> PAQ </td> 
  <td> Morning </td> 
  <td align="right">  25 </td> 
  <td align="right"> 25.00 </td> 
  <td align="right"> 4.00 </td> 
  <td> </td>
  <td style="color: limegreen; font-weight: bold;">OK</td>  
</tr>
```

Visually it looks like so (the table can vary in nrow but the columns are always the same):

[image]

Foot note: I don't use DT, I know of formatStyle however I don't wish to rewrite all of the tables in this project

Obligatory reproducable example:

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

dt.req_team <- data.table("Date" = "2020-09-10", "Team" = "PAQ", "Shift" = "Morning", "InShift" = 25, "AlwPerc" = 25, "AbsPerc" = 4)
dt.req_team[, `Accepted?` := ifelse(AbsPerc >= AlwPerc, "DENIED", "OK")]
dt.req_team[`Accepted?` == "OK", "Accepted?"] <- '<td style="color: limegreen; font-weight: bold;">OK</td>'
dt.req_team[`Accepted?` == "DENIED", "Accepted?"] <- '<td style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">DENIED</td>'

ui <- fluidPage(
  tableOutput("Example")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$Example <- renderTable(dt.req_team, sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I think it comes from parsing your table; I mean `renderTable` has to wrap the contents of your data.frame in `<td></td>`, so you end up with something like `<td><td style="color: limegreen; font-weight: bold;">OK</td></td>` that probably gets parsed wrong. Actually, `xtable` is responsible for creating the html tables. You could try some [hacky formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15403903/create-tables-with-conditional-formatting-with-rmarkdown-knitr/15405068#15405068), but in the end it is not made to easily apply formatting

Comment: Therefore I think you're nevertheless better off using a package that allows easier formatting

Comment: Using `<td>` will render a duplicate table cell element, which looks like it's interpreted as an extra column (I'm guessing this is to prevent nested `<td>` elements which can result in unexpected layout issues). Instead, change `<td>` to `<span>`. The value will be rendered as a child element of the table cell (as opposed to a sibling element).

Comment: @dcruvolo so simple yet so efficient. Thank you very much for the suggestion, it works perfectly!